# why $\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i, j} \mathbf{A}^{(t)}(i, j)\left\|\mathbf{y}_i-\mathbf{y}_j\right\|_2^2$ can boils down to a generalized eigen-problem

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-graph-theory, generalized-eigenvector

I'm reading a paper, it writes "$\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i, j} \mathbf{A}^{(t)}(i, j)\left\|\mathbf{y}_i-\mathbf{y}_j\right\|_2^2$ can boils down to a generalized eigen-problem" (snapshot: [part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3Hyl.png) and [part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOjsT.png)). But I don't know why. May anyone explain it for me?

Comment: I suggest you are writing out problem in full. Pictures are not searchable. Also, what is your background$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe you can give the reference of the paper ? Are there any supplementary conditions on the vectors $\mathbf{y}_i$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that the adjacency matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is symmetric and consider the matrix $\mathbf{Y}$
whose $n$th row is $\mathbf{y}_n^T$.

Part 1: It is straightforward to see that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\phi(\mathbf{Y})
&=&
\frac12 \sum_{i,j} \mathbf{A}_{ij}
\left\|\mathbf{y}_i-\mathbf{y}_j\right\|_2^2 \\
&=&
\frac12 \sum_{i,j} \mathbf{A}_{ij}
\left\|\mathbf{y}_i\right\|_2^2 +
\frac12 \sum_{i,j} \mathbf{A}_{ij}
\left\|\mathbf{y}_j\right\|_2^2
-
\sum_{i,j} \mathbf{A}_{ij}
\mathbf{y}_i^T\mathbf{y}_j \\
&=&
\sum_{i} 
\left( \sum_j \mathbf{A}_{ij} \right)
\mathbf{y}_i^T\mathbf{y}_i
-
\sum_{i,j} \mathbf{A}_{ij}
\mathbf{y}_i^T\mathbf{y}_j \\
&=&
(\mathbf{D-A}):\mathbf{Y}\mathbf{Y}^T \\
&=&
\mathbf{L}:\mathbf{Y}\mathbf{Y}^T \\
&=& \mathrm{tr}(\mathbf{Y}^T \mathbf{L} \mathbf{Y})
\end{eqnarray*}
where $\mathbf{L}=\mathbf{D-A}$ and
$\mathbf{D}$ is the diagonal matrix
with elements
$D_{ii}=\sum_j A_{ij}$.

Here the column operator $:$ denotes the Frobenius inner product between two products $\mathbf{A}:\mathbf{B}=\sum_{ij} A_{ij}B_{ij} = \mathrm{tr}(\mathbf{A}^T  \mathbf{B})$.

Part2 : Setting the gradient to $0$ yields the linear system
$\mathbf{LY}=\mathbf{0}$.
The eigenvalue remains to be found but this is clearly the right path.
I assume some hypotheses are missing to go further...